# Libsvm Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, libsvm

The following libsvm matlab code keeps giving me an Index exceeds matrix dimensions after a few loops. Can anyone help me with where the error might be coming from?

```
testlabel = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0; 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]; 

model = cell(3,1);
for n=1:3
    model{n} = svmtrain(completelabel{n}, completefeatureVector{n}, '-b 1 -t 0');
end

numTest=10;

pr = zeros(numTest,2);
for k=1:numTest
    for m=1:3
        [~,~,p] = svmpredict(testlabel(m, k), featureVectortest{k}, model{m}, '-b 1');
        pr(:,k) = p(:,model{m}.Label==m);    %# probability of class==k
    end
    [~,predictedLabel] = max(pr,[],2);
end
```

Comment: Use a debugger. Also give us some more information about the problem. On which line does the problem occur? For what value of k and m does it happen. Probably in this process, you will find the answer yourself.

Comment: Please shows us, the content of the `completelabel` and `completefeatureVector` routines|vectors...